# Why is $a\cos(2\theta)-b\sin(2\theta)=-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(2\theta-\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{b}))$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

So I entered the expression on the left: $a\cos(2\theta)-b\sin(2\theta)$ into wolframalpha yesterday, and it gave me the expression on the right, which is $-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(2\theta-\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{b}))$ as an alternate expression. I tried several ways like drawing a triangle and stuff like that but I can't seem to understand why they are equivalent, I feel like this is something that's not extremely hard, but I just can't seem to get why it is the way it is. Is it something related to complex numbers, or trig identities? Why are they equivalent?

Comment: Factor out $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, then notice the coefficients represent a point $(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})$ on the unit circle, so it must be $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ for some angle $\phi$. The slope of the line through this point is $m=-b/a=\tan\phi$, so you can solve $\phi=-\tan^{-1}(b/a)$. Then you can factor $\cos\phi\cos2\theta+\sin\phi\sin2\theta$ as $\cos(2\theta-\phi)$ using sum-angle formulas from trig. If you use the complementary angle instead of $\phi$ you get the WolframAlpha formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @runway44